# Using CSS, how can I create a rotated triangle that autosizes with the text content?

Tags: html, css

I need to add a badge in the upper left corner of a div. The badge needs to autosize based on the text content.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbick/npxaasht/

```
<article>
    <div class="triangle"> 
        <span>NEW</span>
    </div>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="triangle"> 
        <span>BACK ORDERED</span>
    </div>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</article>
```

There are two elements with a different amount of text. "NEW" fits well because the values are hardcoded. "BACK ORDER" extends off the triangle.

I need the triangle to autosize so that the triangle will change size to fit the text.

Is this possible using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be possible to automatically resize the triangle using CSS only (you would need some Javascript).

However, if you want a CSS only solution (that isn't quite automatic, but it would work if you don't have too many different labels), here is a new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npxaasht/1/) that fixes your issue.

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <div class="triangle" type="new"> 
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</article>
<article>
    <div class="triangle" type="backorder"> 
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</article>
```

**New CSS** (you must keep the old one too)

```
.triangle[type=new] span::before{
    content: "NEW";
}

.triangle[type=backorder] span::before{
    content: "BACK ORDER";
}

.triangle[type=backorder]{
    border-bottom: 80px solid #f16a6c;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    margin-left:-62px;
    top:-32px;
}
```